# Error installing any gems on IronRuby

Tags: ruby, ironruby

I am brand new to Ruby as of today. I installed IronRuby as I am a .NET developer and it seems to have a lighter footprint for Windows 7.

Things have been proceeding well, until I needed to install a Gem to parse HTML. I am issuing the following command:

```
igem install rokogiri
```

and receiving the following error:

```
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (NoMethodError)
    undefined method `set_params' for #<OpenSSL::SSL::SSLContext:0x00001ba>
```

Running igem env yields:

```
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 1.3.7
  - RUBY VERSION: 1.9.2 (2010-08-18 patchlevel 0) [i386-mswin32]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: C:/Program Files (x86)/IronRuby 1.1/Lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: "C:/Program Files (x86)/IronRuby 1.1/bin/ir.exe"
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: C:/Program Files (x86)/IronRuby 1.1/bin
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - universal-dotnet-4.0
  - GEM PATHS:
     - C:/Program Files (x86)/IronRuby 1.1/Lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1
     - P:/.gem/ironruby/1.9.1
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :benchmark => false
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - http://rubygems.org/
```

My searches on Google have been fruitless. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The error happens in using OpenSSL library.
So this problem can be solved to use ruby standard OpenSSL library, not the library of IronRuby.
I think you can install the library in the following procedure.

---

Invalidate the function of SSL verifying once.
Add the next line to ~/.gemrc(%HOME%\.gemrc) file.
(if it doesn't exit, create)

```
:ssl_verify_mode: 0
```

In this, 'igem' is usabled.
But this state isn't recommend.

Install OpenSSL library, like this :

```
> igem install rubysl-openssl
```

And, restore ~/.gemrc file.
'igem' remains to be usabled.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else that comes across this a solution that worked for me was to use the standard Ruby gem command and set the install directory to the IronRuby gem location.

```
gem install --install-dir "c:/Program Files (x86)/IronRuby 1.1/lib/ironruby/gems/1.8" -V  json_pure
```

igem does look like it's a very basic Ruby script that wraps up the Ruby gem command. The OpenSSL error seems to be a bit of a red herring and is probably because the default gem repository URL now redirects to a different location and the igem script doesn't deal with that.